# Regex for find multiline form data (php)

Tags: php, regex

I try (without success) to make a regex for find a  submit button even if button code is in one two or more lines.

I use now this patter

`/<(button|input)(.*type=['\"](submit|button)['\"].*)?>/i`

and works fine if the button code is in one line

`<input type="submit" name="mybutton" class="button_class" value="Submit" title="Click Me" />`

I want to make it work if my button code look like

`<input type="submit" name="mybutton"`

`class="button_class" value="Submit"`

`title="Click Me" />`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression to parse HTML.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Learn xpath, and use a parser.

**EDIT** Added some code to insert before.

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $x = new DOMXPath($dom);        
    foreach($x->query("//input[@type='submit']") as $node)
    {
         $newNode = $dom->createElement("img");
         $newNode->setAttribute("src","/loading.gif");
         $node->insertBefore($node);    
    }
    $output = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This works fine but doesnt help me, I use preg_replace_callback for find button and insert some text before, If  I use DOM  I dont see how I can insert some text before or after result
Can you guide me a little?

Answer (score 3):

Add `s` (not `m`) as a [modifier](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
/<(button|input)(.*type=['\"](submit|button)['\"].*)?>/is
```

> **s (PCRE_DOTALL)**
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot
>   metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines.
>   Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's
>   /s modifier. A negative class such as
>   [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting
>   of this modifier.

---

> **m (PCRE_MULTILINE)**
>
> By default, PCRE treats the subject
>   string as consisting of a single
>   "line" of characters (even if it
>   actually contains several newlines).
>   The "start of line" metacharacter (^)
>   matches only at the start of the
>   string, while the "end of line"
>   metacharacter ($) matches only at the
>   end of the string, or before a
>   terminating newline (unless D modifier
>   is set). This is the same as Perl.
>   When this modifier is set, the "start
>   of line" and "end of line" constructs
>   match immediately following or
>   immediately before any newline in the
>   subject string, respectively, as well
>   as at the very start and end. This is
>   equivalent to Perl's /m modifier. If
>   there are no "\n" characters in a
>   subject string, or no occurrences of ^
>   or $ in a pattern, setting this
>   modifier has no effect.

Comment: If I use s tag preg_replace_callback function return me all code before first `<input type="submit"...`

Comment: @Fane: It's supposed to do that. If you want an answer to that problem I suggest you either ask a new question or improve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/s` to the end of the regular expression to make `.` match any character, including newlines.

It's also a good idea to change greedy `.*` to lazy `.*?` in order to stop it matching whole chunks of the HTML.

It's still not recommended to use regex for parsing HTML.